# PHP Today echo Tomorrow echo something else

Tags: php, date, datetime

This code does not work. It echo is blank. PHP version: PHP Version 5.0.5

```
$today=(int)date("j");  # today
$statedate=12;
if ((int)$startdate == (int)$today){
    echo '12th';
}
if ((int)$startdate == (int)$today){
    echo '14th';
}
```

Comment: clearly as today is the 12th, it should echo "12th"

Comment: Why do you have 2 `if` with the same condition?

Comment: so how do I do a query for tomorrow and the next day and other days?

Comment: Too localized, just a typo. Also why don't you just use `date("jS")` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$today=(int)date("j");  # today
$statedate=12; //NEVER USED!
if ((int)$startdate == (int)$today){
    echo '12th';
}
if ((int)$startdate == (int)$today){
    echo '14th';
}
```

You are defining `$statedate` and **not** `$startdate`

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid heh? whats `SeRPRo`?

Comment: how can I check the 14th? and 15th?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid thats a completely different question.

Comment: Basically, I want to do, any date from the 12-25th, show an include for that date, so 12 then include ("12.php") and 25 do the same.. thinking an array rather than 10 if else statements??

Comment: its the best solution for my client ATM. That is what I want can you tell me if an array can do this?

Answer (score -2):

sure (int)$today will give you something like the number of days past 1970?
I would suggest you first of all simply write

```
echo '' . (int)$today;
```

to see what the value is, then you will know how to write the if statement.